# Скрипты автоматизации SSH

Tags: ssh, putty, автозапуск

Приветствую вас, уважаемые гуру)

Есть немного наивный вопрос, возможно ли под putty написать скрипты? У меня есть несколько действий, которые, в целом, не сложны, но очень долго копаться по псевдоменюшкам в консоли, и выбирать нужное значение, хотелось бы просто запускать скрипт, который по заданному пути выбирает нужный отсек. Грубо говоря - скрипт на запуск, скрипт на выполнение, скрипт на сохранение и скрипт на выход.

Если есть идеи, или линк, буду благодарен.

Comment: Объясните подробнее, какая конечная цель.

Comment: Цель проста: клик - прошел логин, клик - прошло выполнение команды и т.д. Избавить меня от копания в меню сервера

Comment: Если я правильно понял - putty тут просто для примера, а тебя интересует скриптование действий на удаленном хосте?

Comment: нет, конкретно putty

Comment: plink заюзай

Comment: так в чём проблема? Напишите shell скрипт :)

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю использовать PAC Manager. Он кк раз для того и нужен по сути.http://sourceforge.net/projects/pacmanager/